# Concise way to convert all files in current folder for multiple extensions maintaining their name using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a folder with different types of files. I want to convert all those ending e.g. with

```
.ogg .flac, .m4a
```

using a command that works in this way

```
converter inputfilename outputpath/ouputfilename.outputextension
```

I have tried

```
for audfile in *.ogg *.m4a *.flac; do
    filename=${audfile%.*}
    converter "$audfile" "done/$audfile.mp3"
done
```

That has als the problem that prints
No such file or directory
For each extension that has no file matching (it is more elegant to ignore formats with no matching).
What do you suggest to do it correctly and in a concise way?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: @glennjackman I have thought it was clear enough for the title, I have clarified now, See the edit. thanks.

Comment: Instead of `"done/$audfile.mp3"`, I think you meant `"done/$filename.mp3"`; if so, then you could combine the 2 lines in body of the for-done loop into 1 line, obtaining the slightly more concise `converter "$audfile" "done/${audfile%.*}.mp3"`

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob` is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

It is often said that you shouldn't iterate over directory output, I'd guess that wildcard globbing with `*` would be similar.

Instead you should use the `-exec` option for `find` eg

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.ogg" -exec converter {} done/{}.mp3 \;`

This says "find in the current directory (and don't go looking any deeper) any files ending in .ogg and run the command converter filename.ogg done/filename.ogg.mp3"

The find command should handle any escaping that needs doing, so both `The Hedgehog Song.ogg` and `The_Hedgehog_Song.ogg` would be handled properly.

Comment: thanks, could you report the syntax for multiple extension types? also could you explain why iteration through directory output isn't recomended?